# date-fns/format always takes local timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, date-fns

From below code:

```js
const dateString = '1994-09-15T12:00:00-03:00';
const parsedDate = parseISO(dateString)
const dateFormat = 'MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss xxx'
console.log(format(parsedDate, dateFormat, { }))
```

I expect:
`09-15-1994 20:30:00 -03:00` But i get `09-15-1994 20:30:00 +05:30` as my local timezone is `+05:30`

What am i missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure if the `:` is supported by every browser, try `1994-09-15T12:00:00-0300` instead

Comment: @Lk77 Thanks, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

The `parseDate()` creates a date based on GMT, e.g. is adjusted by 3h based on your input `'1994-09-15T12:00:00-03:00'`.

The `format()` function with `xxx` formats local time without the `Z`, such as `-08:00`, `+05:30`, `+00:00`. If you want to format with GMT string, specify `OOOO`, which will give you something like `GMT-08:00`, `GMT+05:30`, or `GMT+00:00`, which again has the offset adjusted based on your browser's time zone.

See Time-Zones docs below if you want to format to a time zone other than your browser's one, such as GMT-03:00.

Docs:

- ISO 8601: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601
- `parseDate()`: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.2/docs/parseISO
- `format()`: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.2/docs/format
- Time-Zones: https://date-fns.org/v2.29.2/docs/Time-Zones